# <li> element has height and width despite being set to inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists, inline

I get frustrated when CSS always does things I do not expect it to. I thought that inline elements could not have a height or width yet in this tutorial I am going through the `<il>` element I set to be inline shows to have height and width.

I have tried removing elements to find out what causes it to no avail. I am hoping someone more knowledgeable on this could explain why this is happening so I know for future reference.

If you paste this code into an editor and look at the `<li>` tags they have a height and width despite being inline.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Image Gallery</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #333333;
                color: #eaeaea;
            }
            #gallery { position: relative; }
            figure { 
                position: absolute;
                left: 280px;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: .25; 
            }
            #gallery ul { 
                width: 300px; 
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            #gallery li {
                display: inline; 
                float: left;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            #gallery img { border-style: none; }



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
        <div id="gallery">
            <figure>
                
            </figure>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="180" height="75">
                        <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="400" height="300" alt="Golden Gate Bridge">
                            <br>
                        Golden Gate Bridge</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="100" height="75" alt="rocky coastline">
                        <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="400" height="300" alt="Rocky coastline">
                            <br>
                        Rocky Coastline</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="100" height="75" alt="clouds moving in on the coast">
                        <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="400" height="300" alt="clouds moving in on the coast">
                        <br>Clouds Moving in on the Coast</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="100" height="75" alt="waterfall near Big Sur">
                        <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="400" height="300" alt="waterfall near Big Sur">
                        <br>Waterfall Near Big Sur</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="100" height="75" alt="waves crashing on the coast">
                        <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="400" height="300" alt="waves crashing on the coast">
                        <br>Waves Crashing in on the Coast</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href=""><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="100" height="75" alt="sunset on the coast">
                        <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFzF.png" width="400" height="300" alt="sunset on the coast">
                        <br>Sunset on the Coast</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I pasted your code into an inline snippet and don't see what you describe. Please edit your question so we have a [mcve]

Comment: Yes I realised the images do not load, I'll repost with sample images

Comment: Well, it's not just the images. The list items seems to be doing what I'd expect them to

Comment: I replaced the images